# big insert query fails Hibernate\Postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm trying to find out the root cause of failure in existing system. I don't know much about it, but looks like the issue is in inserting big row into Postregsql via Hibernate.
It fails to insert record w/ TEXT field which is about 50-100k size.

Should not be an issue for postgresql itself. But I guess there might be some settings\parameters in hibernate which can affect it. Any suggestion for the search direction?

Comment: If you have a failure, you must have an exception. I'd start looking at its message (if I could see it).

Comment: logs looks clean, so it looks like issue on hibernate side

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails". Do you have an error? Is the text truncated? Is the row inserted without this column? Is the insert silently ignored? Do you see the insert SQL query generated by Hibernate? Where is the code doing the insert? Is it so secret that you can't show it to us? You make it very hard for us to help you by not giving any detail.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the product. Don't have direct access to instance which has this problem. Haven't got any exceptions in avaliable logs. Database persistance logic is spread accross many classes so I don't undestand it myself yet. Giving all these facts I had asked only for suggestion for search directions ))) I don't excpect somebody can give me solution based on this description ))) All what I have now it's symptom like big record is not inserted into DB.

Answer (score 1):

- First I try to look at the exception,
  if it's in your local machine or a
  server log, to get more clues. Since
  you say it's when inserting a row,
  maybe you know where it's happening.
- Try inserting a row where the text
  field has only a few bytes to see if
  that works. Maybe the connection is
  slow and inserting more than 50k
  causes a timeout followed by a
  rollback.
- Also check out if that insertion
  belongs to a much larger transaction
  or it's executing on a smaller one.
- Try doing that insertion in plain jdbc (just temporarily) to see if that works and rule out connection issues.
- If the problem is not in the connection then you can start tweaking Hibernate parameters. Maybe disabling the 2nd cache. The stack exception or a debugging session will be helpful to know what parameters to change.